# How do I use an accumulator with a for loop range in Python?

Tags: python, accumulator

I am trying to use an accumulator in Python but I cannot get it to work. I want the population to start out at 2 and increase by the percentIncrease input but it is not coming out correctly. What am I doing wrong? I know it is how I am accumulating it but every attempt I have tried has failed.

```
#Get the starting number of organisms
startingNum = int(input('Enter the starting number of organisms:'))

#Get the average daily increase
percentIncrease = float(input('Enter the percentage of average daily increase of organisms:'))

#Get the number of days to multiply
number_of_Days = int(input('Enter the number of days to multiply:'))

population = 0
cumPopulation = 0

for number_of_Days in range(1,number_of_Days + 1):
    population = startingNum
    cumPopulation += population *(1+percentIncrease)
    print(number_of_Days,'\t',cumPopulation)


#So inputs of 2, .3, and 10 should become:
1   2
2   2.6
3   3.38
4   4.394
5   5.7122
6   7.42586
7   9.653619
8   12.5497
9   16.31462
10  21.209
```

Comment: Are you sure `population = startingNum` is what you need? You reset `population` in every iteration currently. And please post example input with the ouput you are getting, and what the output should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure do you need to print day 1 as the `startingNum` or day 1 as `startingNum * (1+ percentIncrease)`.

This is what you want:

```
#Get the starting number of organisms
startingNum = int(input('Enter the starting number of organisms:'))

#Get the average daily increase
percentIncrease = float(input('Enter the percentage of average daily increase of organisms:'))

#Get the number of days to multiply
number_of_Days = int(input('Enter the number of days to multiply:'))

printFormat = "Day {}\t Population:{}" 
cumPopulation = startingNum

print(printFormat.format(1,cumPopulation))

for number_of_Days in range(number_of_Days):
    cumPopulation *=(1+percentIncrease) # This equals to cumPopulation = cumPopulation * (1 + percentIncrease)
    print(printFormat.format(number_of_Days+2,cumPopulation))
```

Output:

```
Enter the starting number of organisms:100
Enter the percentage of average daily increase of organisms:0.2
Enter the number of days to multiply:10
Day 1    Population:100
Day 2    Population:120.0
Day 3    Population:144.0
Day 4    Population:172.8
Day 5    Population:207.36
Day 6    Population:248.832
Day 7    Population:298.5984
Day 8    Population:358.31808
Day 9    Population:429.981696
Day 10   Population:515.9780352
Day 11   Population:619.17364224
```

Comment: `cumPopulation = 0` is useless then... and your print statement depends on the version of python. Would be better with `print("{}\t{}".format(numberofdays,cumpop))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yup! didn't delete the extra line. Updated.

Comment: also: the last value is not printed, since the print is the first instruction of your loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, it is intentional. Check the input and output.

Comment: 10 days of multiplication. Day 1 is the initial state. Day 2 to 11 is the 10 days of multiplication.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, True! I guess I can print the day 1 outside the loop, change the loop range and switch the print statement with the cumPopulation calculation.

Comment: that's really better now.

Answer (score -1):

Move `population = startingNum` to outside the loop.